# How to entangle two particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-information

After learning about quantum entanglement I wanted to know, what is the simplest way to entangle two particles in a lab?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does one produce entanglement?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112598/)

Comment: @Gigi Butbaia: your answer to that question doesn't address the question. The question was how to take two non-entangled particles, and entangle them. But, please see my comment to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the answers to "How does one produce entanglement?" gives an example of how to obtain pairs of entangled particles. However, it is a complicated example. The simplest procedure, and widely used in experiments, is down-conversion of ultraviolet (UV)  photons. Such photons are sent on a type of crystal that we name "non-linear crystal". In short, inside the crystal, the UV photon is split into two photons, one of them we name signal photon, the other idler photon. This topic is covered in Wikipedia under the name Spontaneous Parametric Down Conversion.

However, I believe that you ask how can we take two particles, and obtain an entangled pair.

Here is a simple procedure: send upon a 50-50% beam-splitter (BS) two photons of identical wavelength, but have polarization perpendicular to one another, e.g. one photon polarized in the direction x, and the other one in the direction y.
Select only the cases in which at each output of the BS we have one photon (the selection may be done later by checking if we obtained two photons in coincidence).

The two photons are in the state

|S> = (1/sqrt(2)) { $|x>_A$ $|y>_B$ + $|y>_A$ $|x>_B$ } ,

where A and B are the two outputs.

Good luck !